# "However, I hated it extremely" vs "However, I extremely hated it," when telling a flashback?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

Both of these probably mean the same thing but I don't know which one 'sounds' better.

Comment: Could be "Extremely, however, hated I it."  Depends on what you're trying to imply and what the context is.

Comment: Personally, I would say that the first is more natural. But there's nothing wrong with either version.

Comment: @JasonBassford Except for the part about hating something ‘extremely’, which is highly unidiomatic. _Extremely_ does not usually modify active verbs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd say *I really hated it* would be the most common expression. Possibly followed by *I hated it a lot*. But the question is more about the placement of the adverb than it is about the word choice. (Interestingly, *a lot* can seemingly only come after.)

Answer (score 0):

Neither sounds natural to me. **Extremely** is used before *adjectives*, not verbs.

To express the same sentiment, you could say any of these:

- However, I hated it very much. (and, less commonly, "However, I very much hated it.")
- However, I despised it.
- However, I detested it.
- However, I loathed it.